# Invariant forms on principal bundles

Tags: differential-topology, fiber-bundles, principal-bundles

Let $\pi:M \to B$ be a principal $G$-bundle and $\xi$ a invarint $k$-form on $M$. Does $k> dimG$ implies that $\xi$ is a basic form (pull back of a $k$-form on the base manifold $B$)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certainly not. Consider the wedge product of, say, the ($G$-invariant) volume form on the fiber with a basic form.